# Struggle to bind certain keyboard shortcuts to windows tiling on Linux Mint XFCE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, dualboot, key-binding, windows-key

I use Linux Mint 21 xfce, as a dualboot on a laptop with native Win10 (Acer Aspire E571). I struggle to make certain window displacement shortcuts work. In "Windows Manager" I've set "Super + Left/Right/Up/Down" to be the shortcuts for windows tiling, but these key combinations have no effect. However, "Alt + L/R/U/D" works just fine. The Super key itself also functions as expected. What may cause such a problem? I've searched on the forums, but the answer does not seem to be found there. Apologies for my poor Linux and English skills.